# Remove unwanted characters from list elements python

Tags: python-3.x

Input:

```
list1 = ['12','13','14\n50x','44','56\n100x','65\n200x']
```

output:

```
list1=['12','13','14','44','56','65']
```

My list may contain \n50x \n100x \n200x etc on some of the list elements. How to remove those?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! You should show how you tried to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the unwanted characters always come after the first `'\n'`, then this might do it:

```py
new_l = [ i.split('\n')[0] for i in list1 ]
```

Comment: Thank you. Its working. All the 3 solution suggested are working.from next time will post what I have tried before asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

use regex, consistent for increasing no of digits and different types of characters

`import re
print([ re.findall('^\d+.',data)[0] for data in list1 ])`

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expressions (https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) and list comprehension, you can do this as

```
import re
list1=[re.sub(r'\n.*','',x) for x in list1]
```